# The keyboard covers the input field in ios - Ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I've been with this same problem for months and I still can't find a solution. I have an application where there are several forms, when focusing on an input field the keyboard covers this input field and the user cannot see anything. This only happens on iOS, on android everything works normal.

In this application I am using ionic 5 with capacitor.

This is how I would like my application to work: [EXAMPLE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEEiA.gif)

It is currently working like this: [EXAMPLE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23DoT.gif)

.HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="formSubmit" (ngSubmit)="formSubmit()">      
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="field-style">
    <input matInput maxlength="35" class="input-form" placeholder="Agregar un alias (opcional)" formControlName="alias">
  </mat-form-field>
  <button mode="ios" class="btn-siguiente-enable" expand="block" type="submit" *ngIf="formSubmit.valid">Siguiente</button>    
</form>
```

.TS

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.initForms();

    Plugins.Keyboard.setScroll({isDisabled: true});

    Plugins.Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillShow', (info: KeyboardInfo) => {
      Plugins.Keyboard.setResizeMode({mode: KeyboardResize.None});
    });

    Plugins.Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillHide', () => {
      Plugins.Keyboard.setResizeMode({mode: KeyboardResize.Native});
    });
  }
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Maybe this [topic](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/keyboard-hides-input-until-i-start-typing/60827/2) can help you

Comment: I'll try to do what you suggest there. But it seems like a lot of code and I have more than 10 forms in my application and the same thing happens in all of them. I think there should be a better alternative...

Comment: this part don't look so long [helper](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/keyboard-hides-input-until-i-start-typing/60827/24) but ok .

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too and it was very problematic for my project. So I had three solutions for this

**Solution 1 :**
In your app.component.ts, try forcing the focus on the element clicked like that :

```
      window.addEventListener('keyboardDidShow', (e) => {
        const elementFocused: any = document.querySelector(':focus');
        if (elementFocused) {
          elementFocused.blur();
          elementFocused.focus();
        }
      });
```

Adding these lines in the `platform.ready` method solved my problem for some cases.

**Solution 2 :** **@Eliseo**
Like he said, adding margin-bottom to simulate the space for the keyboard is also a solution, but if you want to apply it in any input, add it in the `app.component.ts` using `window.addEventListener('keyboardDidShow', (e) => {});` , you can test on `keyboardDidShow` but also `focus` event or `blur`

**Solution 3 :** Programmatically scroll on click.

I defined my variables like this on my .ts :

```
@ViewChild('scrollableContent', { static: false }) scrollableContent: ElementRef;
  private scrollContainer: any;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.scrollContainer = this.scrollableContent.nativeElement;
  }
  private scrollToBottom(): void {
    this.scrollContainer.scrollTop = this.scrollContainer.scrollHeight;
  }
```

And then in my html, i'm doing

```
<div class="my-scrollable-content" #scrollableContent>
 <input (click)="scrollToBottom()">....</input>  // click event or focus
</div>
```

Or you can add the listener on your ts like that :

```
 window.addEventListener('keyboardDidShow', (e) => {
        const elementFocused: any = document.querySelector(':focus');
        if (elementFocused) {
          this.scrollToBottom();
        }
      });
```

It can sound like a little bit magic but that was the only solutions that worked for my case. The scroll method was the one working the best for me.

Comment: I like yor second solution :)

Comment: First solution works well for me. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is two years old, there is a new, easy solution when using @capacitor/keyboard with ionic: The method [scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView?retiredLocale=de) easily allows you to move the current element into view. As soon, as the keyboard did show, you can simply run this method.
I've implemented it this way:

```js
Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow", () => {
  if (document.activeElement) {
     document.activeElement.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "center"});
  }
});
```

As soon as the keyboard is being shown, the input element will automaticaly scroll into view.

Please note, that this will only work with `resize` set to `KeyboardResize.BODY`or `KeyboardResize.IONIC`.

Hope that will help someone.

Comment: This worked for me just add the code in `capacitor.config.ts` to set `KeyboardResize.BODY`
`plugins: { Keyboard: { resize: KeyboardResize.Body } }`

Answer (score 1):

why not enclosed your app in a div with, e.g. margin-bottom:300px? this makes that the keyboard has enougth space.

You can also make a directive that is applied to input type text that emit a value to a subject. If your main app listen the value you can get it

```
export class MarginDirective {
   @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target'])_(){
         this.auxService.marginSubject.next(true)
   }
   @HostListener('blur', ['$event.target'])__(){
         this.auxService.marginSubject.next(false)
   }
   constructor(private auxService:AuxService){}
}
```

Your service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuxService {

  marginSubject:Subject<boolean>=new Subject<boolean>()
  constructor() { }

}
```

In your main.ts inject the servcie as public

```
   constructor(public auxService:AuxService){}
```

And

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div *ngIf="auxService.marginSubject|async" style="height:200px">
```

A fool of all of this in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wztxcj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: If margin-bottom is the solution ionic default app setting must be having this predefined